# automatic height of the container in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote a page, at the top everything is fine, as it should be. And at the bottom I have a history of events. The width of my container is determined automatically (depending on the width of the screen), and the height - no, on different devices different heights (indents at the bottom are different). Is it possible to determine the height automatically (to the end of the screen) ?? Also, I'd like to add a scroll bar at the bottom for this container so that when events appear there, I can scroll through them both bottom and top. I will be grateful for your help.

My page:
[image]

My code:

```html
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color:Colors.white12
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[

            Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        textColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Text('yes',textScaleFactor: 2.5),
                        onPressed: null,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        textColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Text('no',textScaleFactor: 2.5),
                        onPressed: null,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                  Container(
                      child: Text(('20000' == null ? '' : '10000'), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45.0,color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0.0, 0, 20.0),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text("weight", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom:40, left:0, right:0),
                  ),
                  Center(
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 430,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 1.5
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)
                        ),
                        child: new Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                child: Text("history events", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0)
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                      )//Container
                  )
                ]
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _scanQR();
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.qr_code),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,

      ),
    );
  }
```

My scrin (after updating the code)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              textColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Text('yes', textScaleFactor: 2.5),
              onPressed: null,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              textColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Text('no', textScaleFactor: 2.5),
              onPressed: null,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
            )
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 15.0),
        Container(
          child: Text(('20000' == null ? '' : '10000'), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0.0, 0, 20.0),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text("weight", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom: 40, left: 0, right: 0),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(7, 0, 7, 7),
                child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1.5), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            height: 45,
                            child: Text("history events", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
                        Expanded(
                            child: Scrollbar(
                                child: new ListView(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                child: Text("Event 1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 200,
                            ),
                            Container(
                                child: Text("Event 2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 200,
                            ),
                            Container(
                                child: Text("Event 3", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 50,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ))),
                      ],
                    ))))
      ]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            // _scanQR();
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.qr_code),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: but this container takes up the weight of the screen) and I need it to do everything after the word "Weight" (ie the lower half of the screen) as in the photo

Comment: I edited my answer. Check Now.
Added dynamic height container as per content and with scrollbar.

Comment: yes, everything is fine thank you) only I do not understand how to put the words History of events in the cap of the container. That they were from above and in the center

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: a little wrong, the inscription "History of events" should be at the top of the center "(as in my photo) but when I write at the bottom of the podium, this inscription should remain in place

Comment: Updated. "History of Events" remain in place when scrolling.

Comment: I just tried your code), but when I flipped through the bottom of the event it all went down ((

Comment: So this inscription does not change the position in the container when scrolling. But when I scroll down the whole page srolitsitsa down. I added a new photo to the question (in the photo I scrolled down a bit and the whole page moved to the bottom). Thanks for helping

Comment: can you help me solve this question?

Comment: Okay, basically you want scrolling only container part not whole page?

Comment: That's right, I want to scroll the part where the history of events, and the part where the buttons and weight should always be on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the responsive height or width by using `Media Query` .To do that you need to wrap your Scaffold with `Material App` or `Cupetino App` which allows you to use `MediaQuery` .

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}
```

To make the list scrollable simply you can use `ListView.builder`

```
Center(
                  child: Container(
                margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20,right: 15,left: 15),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.5,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 1.5),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                child: new Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        child: Text("history events",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
                  ],
                ),
              ) //Container
                  )
```

I added a little margin to make it looks better.Ofcourse you can also use `MediaQuery` for margin or padding if you want to.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6oXd.png